# Can I make Chromium or Firefox show true URL of a link in the status bar instead of some "final" one?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, url

When I do a Google search like `http://google.ru/search?q=superuser+stackexchange` and then hover the first link with mouse in Chromium or Firefox, the browsers show `https://superuser.com` in the status bar. However, if I click on the link or copy it to clipboard, I invariably get the true URL, which is quite different:

```
https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8ufOX9unSAhUiS5oKHa47DfUQFgghMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHdF9MOLa9udLLPFk3LI38goQun_Q
```

Even such seemingly simple browser as Midori has this "feature". But e.g. Dillo is more truthful, so I suppose the browsers do have some means of knowing the actual URL, and it should be very simple.

How can I make Chromium and Firefox show me *real* URL instead of the "final" or whatever that short URL is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a feature of the Google search results page. `https://superuser.com` is the “true” URL: that’s what Google links to *until you click*. As you click the button, javascript swaps out the link with a new link, just before your browser follows the link.

Comment: Does it? As I mentioned, much more simple browser, Dillo, shows me the long version.

Comment: Possibly Google gives it the long version in the first place, because they know it's not clever enough to swap out the URLs?

Comment: Actually it appears that if I turn off JavaScript, the URL displayed is indeed the long version. So this is the reason why Dillo shows it: it doesn't support JavaScript.